# How to Render Face from face_recognition Encoding

Tags: python, rendering, face-recognition, facial-identification

Is there any way to render a face from the [`face_recognition`](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) Python library encoding, e.g. a line/dot drawing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My oppinion is: no chance. Learn how dlib makes face encodings.

Comment: you can train another network to map from an encoding to a face image. It is known as template inversion in the research literature. Of course, the resulting image will just be an estimate of the actual input image which might be sufficient depending on the use-case

Comment: @i regular How might I do that?